# How to gerenate custom id in spring data r2dbc?

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

When I have many entities and I want to use custom id generators (for example snowflake) with different sequences for each entity, should I write the corresponding generator in each entity or write all the id generators in one configuration class or one configuration class for each entity?

I don't think it can be coded in each entity, because it can only build one in each entity. But what if I use a static `idWorker`? (here `idWorker` is a property in the entity)

The Spring has [examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/r2dbc/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/r2dbc/entitycallback/ApplicationConfiguration.java), but they are too simple.